# DoCmd.FindRecord isn't finding the record in Access VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am not sure if there is another post like this but i think my question is a little different.

I am currently designing a database to track employee training given by employer. My current error I find is adding an employee by using a bound form (frmAddEmployee) to my employees table (tblEmployees).

What I have at the moment that works is VBA code that shows a notification when you enter a value into a textbox for the employee number and it finds a duplicate record in the table. The VBA will also show the record in the same form that corresponds with the value you have entered when you clear the notification.

Here's the code I use for the txtEmpNumber after update:

```
Private Sub txtEmpNumber_AfterUpdate()
Dim EmpNum As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim EmpNr As Integer

'Assign the entered employee number to a variable
EmpNum = Me.txtEmpNumber.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[EmpNumber] = " & "'" & EmpNum & "'"
If Me.txtEmpNumber = DLookup("[EmpNumber]", "tblEmployees", stLinkCriteria) Then
    MsgBox "This employee number, " & EmpNum & ", has already been entered in database." _
           & vbCr & vbCr & "Please check the number.", vbExclamation, "Duplicate information"
    Me.Undo
    'show the record of matched employee number from the employees table
    EmpNr = DLookup("[EmpID]", "tblEmployees", stLinkCriteria)
    Me.DataEntry = False
    DoCmd.FindRecord EmpNum, , , , , acCurrent
    Me.cmdSave.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdNew.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.txtIDNumber.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

The notification shows there is a duplicate value, for example 1234 and shows the record in the table for 1234 but when I try a different value like 5678 then it shows the value again for 1234 and not 5678.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: This may not be the problem, but I notice that after the `Me.Undo`, you look up the `Id`, `EmpNr`, but then use `FindRecord` to search on `EmpNum`. Perhaps you meant to use `FindRecord` with `EmpNr`?

Comment: Or, when you say "it shows the value again", are you talking about the popup notification, or the search for the matching record in the table?

Comment: is it possible to send you an example of the database and you can have a look?

Comment: @AnnL. yes its the matching record

Comment: Use BeforeUpdate events to validate input.

Comment: @Vanzie Was I on the right track with my first comment? Because I notice that you look up `EmpNr`, but don't do anything with it. Were you intending to use it with `FindRecord`?

Comment: @Vanzie Unfortunately, the laptop I'm using doesn't have Office installed, so it wouldn't do any good for you to send me the database.

Comment: @Vanzie (Also, your employer would probably object to you sending data outside the company!)

Comment: still shows same problem

Comment: @AnnL. there will be no information within the tables as you can enter your own xyz  to test

Comment: @Vanzie Can you post a screen shot of your form? I just have some questions about how you set it up, and the easiest way for me to get answers is to see what the form looks like.

Comment: @AnnL. i removed the EmpNr lookup and DIM but it still gives me the same problem. Like for example i add person A to the database and continue to add person B. Now i add person C but accidentally use the same employee number as person B for person C. Now after clearing the notification it should find the record of the employee with that employee number and display that information which should be person B's information but it keeps displaying person A's details (no matter how many persons you add it keeps displaying info for A)

Comment: @AnnL. i have added a link in the body of the question

Comment: This is a wild guess, but try changing `acCurrent` to `acAll`.  See if that makes a difference.

Comment: seems to have worked!

Comment: yay!  I will write this up as a solution, then. It would be nice if you could mark it as accepted when I'm done.

Comment: Here's a link to a quick demo of how StackOverflow works. It should demonstrate someone marking an answer as accepted.

Comment: @Vanzie Never provided the link!  [Demo of marking an answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the problem you are having is that this command:

```
 DoCmd.FindRecord EmpNum, , , , , acCurrent
```

...searches in the *current* field.  But if there isn't a current field (because the form doesn't have the focus), or if the current field is some other field (such as ID), the "find" won't find a match, and the record you're looking at won't change.

The simplest fix would be to change your code to this:

```
 DoCmd.FindRecord EmpNum, , , , , acAll
```

That will search for the value of `EmpNum` in ALL the fields.

But, if there's a chance that the value for `EmpNum` might also appear in other fields than `txtEmpNumber` (for example, if someone has `EmpNum = 12` and someone else is `ID = 12`), this will eventually start "finding" the wrong record.

So I think the best thing to do would be to make sure your current field is `txtEmpNumber` before you execute the `FindRecord`.

```
Me.txtEmpNumber.SetFocus
DoCmd.FindRecord EmpNum, , , , , acCurrent
```

That will ensure it *only* looks in `txtEmpNumber` when it's trying to find the record.

Comment: This will definitely be the answer but I doubt I will run into this problem with other ID fields as each table as it's own unique ID fields. But thank you for you help. I'm still new so I have no idea how to mark as the answer

Comment: @Vanzie You see, by the answer, where there's a number and an up-triangle and a down-triangle?  You should see a checkmark below it. If you click on that, it should mark this answer as "Accepted".  And I believe you'll even get points for accepting an answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim K As String
K = Me!b
a.SetFocus
DoCmd.FindRecord FindWhat:=K, Match:=acStart, MatchCase:=True, Search:=acSearchCurrent, SearchAsFormatted:=True, OnlyCurrentField:=acCurrent, FindFirst:=True
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).